# PostSharp Serialization

Tags: c#, postsharp

> Persistence of aspects between compile time and run time is achieved by serializing aspects ...

From [PostSharp Documentation](http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp-2.1/##PostSharp-2.1.chm/html/7480ca54-61c0-46c5-9914-60a58c3033e8.htm).

For my understanding, this is only important if I use the `CompileTimeInitialize` method in order to set certain values at compile time. I use this very rarely. I think just instantiating aspects would be much faster then deserializing them, isn't it? So wouldn't PostSharp more fast, if I had the option to skip the serialization process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you're talking of CompileTimeInitialize. If you don't need it, you can skip serialization by using MsilAspectSerializer (see <strike>http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp-2.1/Content.aspx/PostSharp-2.1.chm/html/f711d5da-5696-443c-9b42-e67a3d8b7b36.htm</strike> http://doc.postsharp.net/postsharp-2.1/Default.aspx##PostSharp-2.1.chm/html/f711d5da-5696-443c-9b42-e67a3d8b7b36.htm).

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer :) You're right. I'll correct this right now. What are the use cases you had in mind, when developing aspects serializable? I used the `CompileTimeInitialize` only once for a logger. Is serialization faster/better than the runtime access on a reflection object? I could try this by myself, but maybe you have the answer ready to hand.

Comment: Default settings are optimized for ease of use, not for performance. CompileTimeInitialize is generally useful because it's cheaper to compute something at build time and deserialize it than to compute it at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Gael. I read several customer stories about PostSharp, but I never read about an aspect, where compile time initialization was needed. Can you explain any use case?

Comment: For instance, a logging aspect may need to print a string composed of the name of the type, the name of the method, and the type of its arguments. Since all these pieces of information are known at build time, it is better to compute this string in CompileTimeInitialize and to store it in a field, which will be serialized.